# Struts 2 Nested Parameter Question

Tags: jsp, struts2, nested

Suppose that I have a list of business primary key numbers and a java Map of OrderId numbers to Orders. How would I retrieve the order object?

```
Action Form

// assume proper getters and setters and that both objects are initialized
private List<CustomerOrders> orders;
private Map<Integer, Order> orderIdMap;

// JSP

<s:iterator value="orders">
    <s:property value="%{orderIdMap['what_goes_here'].orderDate}" />
</s:iterator>
```

In the "what_goes_here" blank, I've tried the following:

```
%{orders.orderId}
%{orderId}
<s:property value="%{orders.orderId}" />
<s:property value='%{orders.orderId}' />
```

I also tried it without the single quotes before what_goes_here and it didn't work either.

So how do I access the value from the Map using the key which is the current index of the orders list?

Thanks!

Comment: is `orderId` meant to be a property of `CustomerOrders` object or the current index of the orders list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested but try something like

```
<s:property value="%{getOrderIdMap().get([0].getOrderId()).getOrderDate()}"/>
```

Comment: Here's the final syntax that ended up working for me:  <s:property value="%{orderIdMap[orderId].orderDate}" />